# Magento Observers

Tags: magento, observers

hei everyone, i just want to ask a little bit about observer in magento

what the different between **sales_model_service_quote_submit_after** and **sales_order_save_after**

in my case, i have custom field in payment information in onepage checkout. I want to save incrementID and my custom field when Place Order Button is clicked

now i use function to observer this event **sales_model_service_quote_submit_after** ,  and its working

better i use **sales_model_service_quote_submit_after** or **sales_order_save_after** for my case ?

Answer (score 1):

These two events are fired from a different Model in different order:

The **sales_model_service_quote_submit_after** event is fired in **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php:210** inside `submitOrder()` method and it is fired first.

On the other hand, **sales_order_save_after** event is a dynamic event that is fired in **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:466** inside `_afterSave()` method and it is fired last.

If you want to use this functionality in the frontend, both functions would work fine, but if you also want it to work in case someone creates a new order from the admin panel, you better use **sales_order_save_after** because **sales_model_service_quote_submit_after** is not fired from there.